# Map subdomains to public ip and ports

Tags: dns, port, subdomain

I have a router with a **Public IP** and a set of servers running in a **private network**. I purchased a domain name and I want to map a set of subdomains to several ports of the router which are port forwarded to access the servers from the private network. For instance:

```
subdomain1.mydomain.com → PUBLIC_IP:PORT1
subdomain1.mydomain.com → PUBLIC_IP:PORT2
```

Are there any free DNS services capable of doing this? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can add subdomain records to the domain registrar itself, DNS records are free by your registrar (eg. godaddy, aws, google domain etc.)

All you need to do is -

1. Map subdomain to the public IP of your router.
2. At router,do the port forwarding based on hostname to the appropriate internal ip.

This should just work post this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some pictorial information to the Mdeora's answer.

You can use proxy to forward your request to your private machine/instances.

- Here is my configuration to add subdomain. I am using AWS Route53 and I have registered domain.

[image]

- Here are subdomain registered with my domain.

[image]

- To give you a better idea of how to forward the request, here is the picture from `docs.docker.com`. This can help you to understand some details and map this according to your requirement

[image]

Reference : https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/